# Python prime number checker function

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, primes

I was bored, and I was watching a sci-fi show where people were starting out during a long systems check asking each other whether numbers were prime or not, sort of passing the time as they do their inspections.

The show is irrelevant, but I wondered if I could build a prime number checker in Python 3 that would be very quick.  I know this has been done before, but I was curious whether I could do it on my own.

Now, this works fine for smaller numbers, and is pretty darn quick, a second or two.  But for large numbers, it takes a really long time.

I'm not a coder by profession, though, so I'm pretty sure this could be improved.  Any speed improvements are welcome.

Required `import`s, and the 'test' function which takes input of a number and spits out the results is below,

Currently, the results spit out a tuple, the first value either being Boolean or the number '0' (because the number '1' is a unique case that is not prime but you can't just say 'False' for), and a short string description.

```
from typing import AnyStr, Optional, Union

def is_prime(num: int) -> (Optional[Union[bool, int]], Optional[AnyStr]):
    if num <= 1:
        return 0, "Neither prime nor composite."

    if num <= 3:
        return True, "Prime"

    for i in range(2, num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
            return False, "Not Prime"

    return True, "Prime"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = int(input("Value: "))
    print(is_prime(n))
```

I'm curious how I can improve the performance of this code for larger numbers so that it's a fairly *fast* function, rather than taking a very long time to iterate over values.  I know that the iterations in the `for` loop are taking the hugest amount of time, but I'm not a mathematician so I'm not sure the 'best' approach for speeding up this.  Don't yell at me too harshly, this was more a quick 'mind test' to see if I could come up with something that worked.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>Disclaimer: I can read Python, but I'm not a Python developer.</sup>

First of all, your code follows PEP8, which is a plus (although a second empty line before `is_prime` is necessary). And it's great that you try static type hints.

However, there are two things amiss here. First of all, `Optional` isn't honest at that point. We *always* return a value. And we *always* return a `str`, not `AnyStr`. We should therefore change the type hints accordingly:

```
from typing import Union


def is_prime(num: int) -> (Union[bool, int], str):
```

If there was a path where we could accidentally return `None, None` or `None, b"12343"`, a static checker should warn us. So no `Optional` or `AnyStr`.

Since the types are now out of a way, let's have a look at documentation before we head to algorithms. A [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) is a nice addition:

```
def is_prime(num: int) -> (Union[bool, int], str):
    """Checks whether the given number is prime."""

    if num <= 1:
    ...
```

You can probably come up with a more detailed one so that the code itself contains the meaning of `True`, `False` and `0`.

Now to the algorithm. Your algorithm has \$\mathcal O(n)\$ worst time complexity. However, for any pair \$x\$,\$y\$, such that \$x < y\$ and \$ x y = n \$ we must have \$x \le \sqrt{n}\$. Therefore, we can stop at `math.ceil(sqrt(n))`, not `n`. This yields \$\mathcal O(\sqrt{n})\$ worst time complexity.

For *very* large numbers this will still be too slow. There are other algorithms for that, which [are out of scope for a small review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801391/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-checking-if-a-number-is-prime).

Comment: Optional is so None is an option.  I agree but the IDEs I have used complain if I do `Union[Any, None]` which the Optional supposedly works for.  The type hints are at the core less relevant than the core of the code.

Comment: It's actually slightly worse than O(sqrt(n)), because n%k is not constant-time.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a mathematician, so I can't comment on 'correct' ways to identify primes - however one possible optimisation is to consider factors.

If a number isn't divisible by n, then it also won't be divisible by any other number for which n is a factor.

For example if a number isn't divisible by 2, then it also won't be divisible by any other even number, since all even numbers can be generated by 2 * something.

I have some ideas about how you could implement this in code, but I'll leave them out the answer for now, as this sounds like a learning example, and it might be an interesting challenge for you to consider them.

(I'm also hopeful that this observation will be surpassed by someone with a mathematical background giving some more info on how to definitively test for primes in an efficient manner!).

Comment: That's right, you would have to skip numbers accordingly. But you would have to remember all primes you already came across. At that point, you didn't just write a primality test, but a prime sieve.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is correct to say that `is_prime(1) = False`. Do you really want to add all this complexity to your function just to handle the special case of n<2? It depends on what you're using it for. If you're just wanting to be able to give Rodney the correct answer, he's probably not giving n<2, and if he does, you can just say "not prime" without running the program. You should consider just raising an error when n<2, rather than complicating the output.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea, to return redundant information of a simple function. If you want to distinguish three cases, `None`, `False` and `True` would be good. If you also want a description, use a dictionary:

```
DESCRIPTION_OF_IS_PRIME_RESULT = {
    None: "Neither prime nor composite.",
    False: "Prime",
    True: "Not Prime",
}
```

Optimizations are, test only every second number and end at sqrt(num):

```
def is_prime(num):
    """ tests if num is a prime
    returns: None for num <= 1 otherwise
       True or False whether num is prime or not  
    """
    if num <= 1:
        return None

    if num % 2 == 0:
        return num == 2

    for i in range(3, int(sqrt(num)) + 1, 2):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False

    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = int(input("Value: "))
    print(DESCRIPTION_OF_IS_PRIME_RESULT[is_prime(n)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Since other answers have covered style and efficiency of your code, I thought I'd contribute with another algorithm. The [Miller-Rabin primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) is a probabilistic primality test which is fast. Really fast. I have implemented it myself in both Java and C++, and it could handle 100-digit numbers in a few milliseconds.

I found a Python 2.7 version of it [here](https://gist.github.com/bnlucas/5857478), and with some very minor changes it works with python 3.x:

```
from random import randrange

def miller_rabin(n, k=10):
    if n == 1:
        return False
    if n == 2 or n == 3:
        return True
    if not n & 1:
        return False

    def check(a, s, d, n):
        x = pow(a, d, n)
        if x == 1:
            return True
        for i in range(s - 1):
            if x == n - 1:
                return True
            x = pow(x, 2, n)
        return x == n - 1

    s = 0
    d = n - 1

    while d % 2 == 0:
        d >>= 1
        s += 1

    for i in range(k):
        a = randrange(2, n - 1)
        if not check(a, s, d, n):
            return False
    return True
```

I have not written this code, but it seems to be working after some slight modifications (before the modifications it would hang on `n = 1`, and give an error for `n = 3`).